# Spring security 3 Concurrent session control not working in tomcat clustered environment

Tags: apache, spring-security, tomcat7

Spring security's concurrent session control is not working properly in tomcat 7 clustered environment but works fine in non-clustered environment.Sessions are also replicated in tomcat.
Configuration for clustering:

```
<Cluster channelSendOptions="6" className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster">
        <Manager className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager" expireSessionsOnShutdown="false" notifyListenersOnReplication="true"/>
        <Channel className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.GroupChannel">
          <Membership address="228.0.0.9" className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.McastService" dropTime="3000" frequency="500" port="45564"/>
          <Receiver address="auto" autoBind="100" className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.nio.NioReceiver" maxThreads="6" port="5008" selectorTimeout="5000"/>
          <Sender className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.ReplicationTransmitter">
            <Transport className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.nio.PooledParallelSender"/>
          </Sender>
          <Interceptor className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.TcpFailureDetector"/>
          <Interceptor className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.MessageDispatch15Interceptor"/>
        </Channel>
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.ReplicationValve" filter=""/>
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteBinderValve"/>
        <Deployer className="org.apache.catalina.ha.deploy.FarmWarDeployer" deployDir="/tmp/war-deploy/" tempDir="/tmp/war-temp/" watchDir="/tmp/war-listen/" watchEnabled="false"/>
        <ClusterListener className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteSessionIDBinderListener"/>
        <ClusterListener className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.ClusterSessionListener"/>
      </Cluster>
```

Configuration for apache load balancing:

```
ProxyPass / balancer://domain.foo.net/ lbmethod=byrequests stickysession=JSESSIONID|jsessionid nofailover=Off maxattempts=15
ProxyPreserveHost On
<Proxy balancer://domain.abcprocure.net>
    BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:8888 max=250 min=45 keepalive=On route=tc02
    BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:8080 max=250 min=45 keepalive=On route=tc01

</Proxy>
```

Further assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default `SessonRegistry` is an in-memory implementation so you will have a different one in each JVM which will be unaware of the others.

You need to implement the `SessionRegistry` interface in a way that shares data between VMs. This could use a SQL database, memcached, redis or whatever is most appropriate for your situation.

Once you've written your class, the [reference manual](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#concurrent-sessions) shows how to configure concurrency control with an explicit `SessionRegistry` bean.